# how to upload file to play and retrieve result

Tags: ajax, post, iframe, file-upload, playframework

I developed an application in `play framework` for converting an uploaded `csv` file to `json` format .
Since this is a webservice , what I need is to create a client html page , to upload a file and convert it to `json` format by using my web service.

But by using `ajax`, `getjson` or `$.post` methods I failed to send the uploaded file to server.

My code is from client html is:

```
function myFunction()
{   
   alert("form data " + $("#form").serialize());
   $.ajax({
        url:"http://mydomain:9999/csvtojson",
        type: 'POST',
        data:  $("#form").serialize(),
        dataType:'json'
    }).done(function (data) {
       alert("data "+data);
       $("#result").html(data); 
    });
}
</script>
</head>
<body>    
      <p>Click the button to trigger a function.</p>
      <form id="form" enctype="multipart/form-data"  method="post"   action="http://mydomain:9999/csvtojson" >
         <input type="file" name="CSVFILE" id="file"/>
         <button type="button"  onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
         <div id="result"></div>
      </form>
```

**Reason :**

`$("#form").serialize()` is empty for the form contain only files.

I tried another way to solve this problem by using `iframe`.

I set the target `json` to `iframe`, and it successfully displays the result there.

But I can not access the data in that `iframe`.

Since due to security reasons , browsers restricted accessing data from iframe , which is loaded from different remote site.

That's the cross domain policy restricting us. It's designed to prevent `cross site scripting (XSS)` attacks.

Is there any way to solve my problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE :**
     Solution:
      In the client side : client want to sent the result page where the result is to  be displayed. Suppose it be result.jsp .

In that result.jsp , get the parameter value and display.

```
In the server side : redirect the result to the page sent by the client.
```

I used Iframe for this, and by the above method , it is possible to read the value from iframe without cross domain problem.